# Difference in way of taking limit of improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

So I need to think of an example of a function $f\colon [-1, 1] \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\int_{-1+t}^{1-2t}f(x)\ dx\neq \lim_{t\to 0}\int_{-1+2t}^{1-t}f(x)\ dx.
$$
My thought was using a trignometric function to play with the $2t$ part, but it's not quite working. Does any elementary function work here or do I need to play with it piecewise?

Comment: Hint: $\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx$ cannot exist, otherwise the two limits would be equal. In particular, $f$ cannot be continuous on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Should I have the function blow up to infinity at -1 and 1? I was thinking of a tangent function, not sure it works though...

Comment: Exactly, you need a blowup: At one side to $-\infty$ and the other side to $+\infty$ so that through cancellations the two limits can exist.

Comment: Thanks, got it now. I had that exact idea from the start but messed up in taking the limit and having things cancel out nicely. I ended up using $f(x)=\tan \frac{\pi}{2}x, -1<x<1$ and $f(x)=0$ elsewhere.